# ggplot2 creates uneven spacing between columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to make a heatmap plot, visualizing activity in various categories over time. I used geom_tile for this purpose, and at first glance it worked perfectly.

[image]

But looking closely at the chart above the spacing between the columns is very uneven. The x axis is Date, and the y axis is a factor, so there is no good reason why the widths of tiles should adapt.

I have tried changing the width of the tiles using aes(width=X), but that does not fix the problem.

Plot code used, where I have removed the elements I knew for sure could not impact this issue:

```
ggplot(monthlyEvents, aes(x=YearMonth, y=EventType, fill=EventRate)) + geom_tile(colour=bgcolor) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels=date_format("%b %Y"), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+ 
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=bgcolor, colour=bgcolor), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=palette, na.value="grey39")
```

Comment: different months have different length, to avoid such situation as decribed I prefer to convert data variables to character or factor before plotting

Comment: This was it! Is this question a duplicate? If so, I'll remove it. Otherwise, feel free to post as answer.

Comment: @inscaven Great tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to add the answer to this question for the sake of anyone else who comes looking.

It turns out what was going on is that when you plot Dates as months using `date_breaks("1 month")`, it doesn't actually use a month interval on the X axis. The X axis is still Date. This means that the months will be unevenly spaced because different months has different number of days.

To fix this problem, I formatted the dates to factor, with the pretty styling I used above, using

```
niceFormatting <- format(events$YearMonth, "%Y %b")
MonthFactor <- factor(niceFormatting, levels = niceFormatting)
```

Plotting with `MonthFactor` as the X axis worked out as I had expected. Without all the formatting:

```
ggplot(monthlyEvents, aes(x=MonthFactor, y=EventType, fill=EventRate)) + geom_tile(colour=bgcolor)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble making the jump from question to answer -- are you still using scale_x_date() somehow? Is there anyway you could show the solution inline with the plot above? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. No, I get rid of the Date type entirely, because the scaling doesn't work right, and also remove scale_x_date. Then just plot on x axis with the string factor. I'll update for clarity. The formatting yields strings of format "2017 aug", which space nice and evenly because they are just a factor with no linear relationship.